# removing value after decimal

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I am converting a string to decimal using `Convert.ToDecimal()`. I am using this in razor engine. What I want is that it should come as rounded off to nearest integer value.

I have tried `Math.round`, `Math.ceil` and `String Format`. I don't know why it is not working.

```
<td data-value="TotalFeesNumeric" data-negative="true" class="lp_currency_format">
  @{if (@Model.CalculatedBreakevenSummary != null &&
  @Model.CalculatedBreakevenSummary.TotalFeesNumeric != null) 
  {@Convert.ToDecimal(Model.CalculatedBreakevenSummary.TotalFeesNumeric)}}
</td>
```

It is not giving an integer value.

Comment: Why are you converting it to a decimal if you want an integer?

Comment: Well, Convert.ToDecimal _returns_ the value converted. It doesn't change the property that you pass to convert. However, I find this code wrong for another reason. You should do this in your Controller code when you prepare the model, not in the razor view

Comment: It is a pre written code.I have been asked to convert it to integer value.I cant make any changes in code

Answer (score 0):

[decimal.Round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round?view=netframework-4.8) *rounds a value to the nearest integer or specified number of decimal places.*

In your case, you could use:

```
decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Model.CalculatedBreakevenSummary.TotalFeesNumeric))
```

..and if you would need the result to be of type `int`, you could just cast it as:

```
(int)decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Model.CalculatedBreakevenSummary.TotalFeesNumeric))
```

Comment: still values are coming in decimal on print screen. :(

Comment: Even with the `(int)` cast??